# Analogy of $[0,1]^n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A probability maps a set (such as 1 dimensional path) to $[0,1]$. Is there a sufficient and necessary analogy of $[0,1]^n$ to a $n-$dimensional cube ? or to $n-$dimensional other well known objects ?

To clarify:

(1)From probability theory, is it sufficient and necessary to obtain the map to $[0,1]^n$ ? This can start with a function or other structures or objects to preserve or generalize the properties in one dimensional case.

(2)From other theory, is it sufficient and necessary to obtain an algebraic object mapping to $[0,1]^n$ ?  There is a special case lifting cubes, but I need to know how to obtain the map to $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: $n$ probabilities ?

Comment: In math, when we speak of analogies, we are always expressing some specific way in which the analogy holds.  So, the question is this: what *property* of the probability are you trying to generalize?  Presumably you aren't just asking if it is possible to find functions from a given set to $[0,1]^n$...

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I don't know about _always_, though it's something to aim for.  For example, I can say off the top of my head that the space $X = \{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}$, with topology generated by the sets $\{x<i\}$ for all $i$, is to the category of spectral spaces as $[0,1]^n$ is to the category of compact Hausdorff spaces.  But it would take me quite some time to say exactly _why_.  Maybe they're some kind of cogenerators?  Maybe they are the respective canonical $n$-simplicies?

I agree that having a list of properties is better than not.  But I think that unfinished math is still math.

Comment: @User-33433 Respectfully, I disagree; without some reason (at least some intuition, even if you aren't completely aware of specifics), you might as well be saying "a horse is to a baseball stadium as complex analysis is to a cheeseburger".  :-)

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson That reflects your own lack of understanding of the statement more than the nature of the statement itself.  I could easily rattle off ten situations where the two play similar roles, if you like.  For example, the construction of the Stone–Čech compactification is isomorphic to Hochster's construction of the spectralification of certain spaces, with $[0,1]$ replaced by the Sierpinski space.  I'm not speaking of a lack of reasons, just arguing that "reasons" may take many intermediate forms between "list of axiomatized properties" and "total absence of thought."

Comment: @User-33433 You have reasons; so, the analogy is meaningful.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Cindy: Please do not move to Math Overflow, it is not really appropriate for that site. And also it is quite appropriate for this site :)